# Kotlin - suspending method has extra branching in byte code while method return type is inline class type

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is a dummy code to explain the issue;

1. First method is a simple method calling another suspending method.
2. Second method is a bit more complex under the hood since it is doing something else as well hence extra byte code will be generated. **I completely understand the reason**
3. The third method is returning a string which is returned by a suspending method.
4. The fourth and fifth methods are returning a custom class type i.e. `StringWrapper`

Note: The `StringWrapper` is an inline class.

```
@JvmInline
value class StringWrapper(val value: String)
```

```
class DummyServiceWrapper {

    private val p = DummyPrinter()

    suspend fun printHello() {
        p.printHello2()
    }

    suspend fun printHello1() {
        val value = p.printHello1()
        print("hey there $value")
    }


    suspend fun printHello2(): String {
        return p.printHello2()
    }


    suspend fun printHello3(): StringWrapper {
        return p.printHello1()
    }

    suspend fun printHello4(): StringWrapper {
        p.printHello1()
        return StringWrapper("Hey there")
    }

}
```

Below is the generated code for the above class;

```
public final class DummyServiceWrapper {
   private final DummyPrinter p = new DummyPrinter();

   @Nullable
   public final Object printHello(@NotNull Continuation $completion) {
      Object var10000 = this.p.printHello2($completion);
      return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : Unit.INSTANCE;
   }

   @Nullable
   public final Object printHello1(@NotNull Continuation var1) {
      Object $continuation;
      label20: {
         if (var1 instanceof <undefinedtype>) {
            $continuation = (<undefinedtype>)var1;
            if ((((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != 0) {
               ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label -= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               break label20;
            }
         }

         $continuation = new ContinuationImpl(var1) {
            // $FF: synthetic field
            Object result;
            int label;

            @Nullable
            public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
               this.result = $result;
               this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               return DummyServiceWrapper.this.printHello1(this);
            }
         };
      }

      Object $result = ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).result;
      Object var6 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
      Object var10000;
      switch (((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            DummyPrinter var7 = this.p;
            ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label = 1;
            var10000 = var7.printHello1-og2vJxQ((Continuation)$continuation);
            if (var10000 == var6) {
               return var6;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            var10000 = ((StringWrapper)$result).unbox-impl();
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
      }

      String value = (String)var10000;
      String var3 = "hey there " + StringWrapper.toString-impl(value);
      System.out.print(var3);
      return Unit.INSTANCE;
   }

   @Nullable
   public final Object printHello2_og2vJxQ/* $FF was: printHello2-og2vJxQ*/(@NotNull Continuation var1) {
      Object $continuation;
      label20: {
         if (var1 instanceof <undefinedtype>) {
            $continuation = (<undefinedtype>)var1;
            if ((((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != 0) {
               ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label -= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               break label20;
            }
         }

         $continuation = new ContinuationImpl(var1) {
            // $FF: synthetic field
            Object result;
            int label;

            @Nullable
            public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
               this.result = $result;
               this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               Object var10000 = DummyServiceWrapper.this.printHello2-og2vJxQ(this);
               return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : StringWrapper.box-impl((String)var10000);
            }
         };
      }

      Object $result = ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).result;
      Object var4 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
      Object var10000;
      switch (((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            DummyPrinter var5 = this.p;
            ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label = 1;
            var10000 = var5.printHello1-og2vJxQ((Continuation)$continuation);
            if (var10000 == var4) {
               return var4;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            var10000 = ((StringWrapper)$result).unbox-impl();
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
      }

      return (String)var10000;
   }

   @Nullable
   public final Object printHello3_og2vJxQ/* $FF was: printHello3-og2vJxQ*/(@NotNull Continuation var1) {
      Object $continuation;
      label20: {
         if (var1 instanceof <undefinedtype>) {
            $continuation = (<undefinedtype>)var1;
            if ((((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label & Integer.MIN_VALUE) != 0) {
               ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label -= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               break label20;
            }
         }

         $continuation = new ContinuationImpl(var1) {
            // $FF: synthetic field
            Object result;
            int label;

            @Nullable
            public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
               this.result = $result;
               this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
               Object var10000 = DummyServiceWrapper.this.printHello3-og2vJxQ(this);
               return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : StringWrapper.box-impl((String)var10000);
            }
         };
      }

      Object $result = ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).result;
      Object var4 = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
      Object var10000;
      switch (((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label) {
         case 0:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            DummyPrinter var5 = this.p;
            ((<undefinedtype>)$continuation).label = 1;
            var10000 = var5.printHello1-og2vJxQ((Continuation)$continuation);
            if (var10000 == var4) {
               return var4;
            }
            break;
         case 1:
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            var10000 = ((StringWrapper)$result).unbox-impl();
            break;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
      }

      String var6 = (String)var10000;
      return StringWrapper.constructor-impl("Hey there");
   }
}
```

**Can someone please explain why it has an extra branching inside the `invokeSuspend`**

Given below,

```
@Nullable
public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
       this.result = $result;
       this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       Object var10000 = DummyServiceWrapper.this.printHello3-og2vJxQ(this);
       return var10000 == IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED() ? var10000 : 
       StringWrapper.box-impl((String)var10000);
}
```

Compared to this when the suspending call does not return a inline type;

```
@Nullable
public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull Object $result) {
     this.result = $result;
     this.label |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     return DummyServiceWrapper.this.printHello1(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When a suspend function is compiled, the compiler will add a `Continuation` type parameter and change the return type to `Object`.

- `Continuation` parameter : To resume at where a function suspended. In `Continuation`, there is a label property to mark a resume point.
- `Object` return type : When a suspend function suspends, `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` is returned. its type is `Any`, which is `Object` in Java.

And according to the [inline value classes document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#representation), inline classes are boxed whenever they are used as another type.

In `StringWrapper`, there are `constructor_impl` and `box_impl`.

- `constructor_impl` : Return the parameter as the value type(`String`), called whenever you create a `StringWrapper` instance. `StringWrapper("string")` in Kotlin is `StringWrapper.constructor_impl("string")` in Java.
- `box_impl` : Box the parameter into `StringWrapper` class. Called when it is needed.

In `printHello4`, `return StringWrapper("Hey there")` in Kotlin will be `return StringWrapper.constructor_impl("Hey There")` in Java, and the return value is `String`. But it need to be boxed as it is represented as `Object`. So it is boxed in `invokeSuspend`.